# Not able to execute script from crontab

Tags: perl, cron, execution, cron-task

I am able to execute scrip from command line.
I'm executing it like this:

```
/path/to/script run
```

But while executing it from cron like below, the page is not comming:

```
55     11 * * 2-6   /path/to/script.pl run   >> /tmp/script.log              2>&1
```

The line which is getting a webpage uses `LWP::Simple`:

```
my $site = get("http://sever.com/page") ;
```

I'm not modyfing anything. The page is valid and accessible. 
I'm getting enpty page only when I execute this script from crontab. I am able to execute itfrom command line!
 Crontab is owned by root. And job is executed as root.

Thanks in advance for any clue!

Comment: We need to know a bit more. Is the crontab owned by you, or is it another user? Where does the `get()` function come from? If it's the one from [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) then that doesn't set `$!` on error, so your error message isn't going to be very helpful.

Comment: Indeed.. I'm using  `LWP::Simple` and `$!` was wrong here. Anyhow I'm not able to get the content from cronjob whereas I'm able to get it from command line. Crontab is owned by root. And I execute this script as root as well.

Comment: Can you add a `wget` or `curl` cron job to rule out whether it's a perl issue or not?

Comment: It doesnt come per wget from cron neither.

Comment: Please switch to the following so you can see what error you are getting: `my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); my $response = $ua->get($url); die($response->status_line()) if !$response->is_success(); my $site = $response->content();`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what might be causing this, but there are differences between your environment, and the environment created by crontab.

You could try running it through a shell with appropriate args to construct your user environment:

```
55 11 * * 2-6 /bin/tcsh -l /path/to/script.pl run >> /tmp/script.log 2>&1
```

I'm assuming you are running it by cron with your own user ID of course. If you aren't, then obviously you should try running it manually with the user ID that cron is using to run it.

Comment: `cron` will also have a different `cwd`, which can cause problems too.

Comment: Yep, there are a few differences, but bash -l should make the environment pretty much like the users shell... unless it's a different user of course :)

Comment: The script is found and is running. BTW: Shell is tsch .The problem is, that the page is not get. All paths are absolute.

Comment: Run it from cron, as your user (the user you are using on the shell where it works) using tsch -l then. See if that works.

Comment: Actually is tcsh (typo). I'm getting Unknown option: `-l'
Usage: tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ].So -l is possible.

Comment: LOL I typo'd it in the comment AND the answer edit, it has happened to me before, I think I sometimes suffer from a kind of literary dyslexia. Odd you're getting a usage error, and it looks like 'l' is listed in the usage error as an option too... Check your man page for your version I guess, but the man page for tcsh I looked at certainly listed -l as meaning 'run as a Login shell', which means it pulls in all your user environment.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a difference in environment variables (e.g. those that specify a proxy to use), I believe you are running afoul of SElinux. Among other things, it prevents background applications (e.g. cron jobs) from accessing the internet unless you explicitly allow them to do so. I don't know how to do so, but you should be able to find out quite easily.